# Custom Stripe Payment for Wordpress having issue

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I notice that plugins like woocommerce and some others, are able to integrate with stripe easily. But when I do my own custom snippet, I am unable to get it to work.

```
Checkout Session creation failed! Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error [errno 77]: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: CApath: none)
```

Instead I keep getting the above error. It talks about the CAfile. How come in Woocommerce payment and others, there isn't this issue? How did they bypass or overcome this?

here is my snippet:

My form:

```
<div id="paymentResponse" class="hidden"></div>
<button class="stripe-button" id="payButton">
    <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
    <span id="buttonText">Pay Now</span>
</button>


<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
// Set Stripe publishable key to initialize Stripe.js
const stripe = Stripe('<?php echo $set['publish']; ?>');

// Select payment button
const payBtn = document.querySelector("#payButton");

// Payment request handler
payBtn.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    setLoading(true);

    createCheckoutSession().then(function (data) {
        if(data.sessionId){
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                sessionId: data.sessionId,
            }).then(handleResult);
        }else{
            handleResult(data);
        }
    });
});
    
// Create a Checkout Session with the selected product
const createCheckoutSession = function (stripe) {
    return fetch("<?php echo get_rest_url(null,'make/stripe/payment'); ?>", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            createCheckoutSession: 1,
        }),
    }).then(function (result) {
        return result.json();
    });
};
```

Here is the payment.

```
//make/stripe/payment
function online_stripe_payment( \WP_REST_Request $req ) {

    $headers = $req->get_headers();
    $auth_token = $headers['authorization'][0];
    $params = $req->get_params();
    require_once(pay_stripe_dir.'init.php');
    //\Stripe::setCABundlePath();
    $set = my_settings();
    // Set API key 
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($set['secret']); 
 
$response = array( 
    'status' => 0, 
    'error' => array( 
        'message' => 'Invalid Request!'    
    ) 
); 
 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
    $input = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
    $request = json_decode($input);     
} 
 
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) { 
    http_response_code(400); 
    echo json_encode($response); 
    exit; 
} 
 
if(!empty($request->createCheckoutSession)){ 
    // Convert product price to cent 
    $stripeAmount = round($productPrice*100, 2); 
 
    // Create new Checkout Session for the order 
    try { 
        $checkout_session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([ 
            'line_items' => [[ 
                'price_data' => [ 
                    'product_data' => [ 
                        'name' => $productName, 
                        'metadata' => [ 
                            'pro_id' => $productID 
                        ] 
                    ], 
                    'unit_amount' => $stripeAmount, 
                    'currency' => $currency, 
                ], 
                'quantity' => 1 
            ]], 
            'mode' => 'payment', 
            'success_url' => $set['success'].'?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}', 
            'cancel_url' => $set['cancel'], 
        ]); 
    } catch(Exception $e) {  
        $api_error = $e->getMessage();  
    } 
     
    if(empty($api_error) && $checkout_session){ 
        $response = array( 
            'status' => 1, 
            'message' => 'Checkout Session created successfully!', 
            'sessionId' => $checkout_session->id 
        ); 
    }else{ 
        $response = array( 
            'status' => 0, 
            'error' => array( 
                'message' => 'Checkout Session creation failed! '.$api_error    
            ) 
        ); 
    } 
}
```

I would expect the script to redirect me to make the stripe payment but it didn't. Instead it throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common cause for the "errno 77" in PHP is that you haven't installed the right certificates when you installed the stripe-php library. Often it's simply that the file in `data/ca-certificates.crt` which you can see [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/data/ca-certificates.crt) is not included in your PHP installation, or it has file permissions that is preventing your code from accessing it.

WooCommerce likely wrote their own logic/layer for communicating with Stripe's API and doesn't need that file and that might explain the discrepancy.

Comment: Thank you! I have downloaded the CRT and set 
\Stripe\Stripe::setCABundlePath(path_to_cert.'ca-certificates.crt');
It then work. :)